# Spring security add ApplicationEventListener to ExpiredJwtException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, jjwt

I had implemented `AuthenticationFailureListener` for fail login by using `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent>` and all my Bad Credentials event are handeled in the same class, very convenient, I have tried to add a Listener to `ExpiredJwtException` or `SignatureException` but I could not figure which event is triggered, I have tried -

```
@Component
public class ApplicationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.toString()); //not printed when ExpiredJwtException thrown
    }
}
```

to catch all `ApplicationEvent` but when one of this exception happens the method `onApplicationEvent` does not fired.
I can catch this Exceptions but I want to handle them globally like `BadCredentialsException` is handled by `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent`.
Tried `AuthenticationFailureExpiredEvent` -

```
@Component
public class ApplicationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureExpiredEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureExpiredEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Expired!!"); //same result
    }
}
```

but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, I would have to check the source, but: it could be that an application event is **not emitted** for `ExpiredJwtException` or `SignatureException`.

Possible solutions are:

1. Publish the event yourself: as you mentioned you are able to catch these exceptions, so a simple solution would be to catch them and then emit the desired event. You just need to autowire the `ApplicationEventPublisher` and then call `publishEvent(event)`.
2. Use a `Filter` to catch and handle the exceptions in a single place.

Example of solution 2:

```
public class AuthFailureFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException | SignatureException exception) {
            handle(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: publishEvent method did the trick, thank you, and I think that because this exceptions are not part of spring framework(part of 
`io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException`)  no event was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to publish an `ApplicationEvent` when catching exceptions is by using the `ApplicationEventPublisher`.  There is no need to implement `ApplicationEvent` using this method as it wraps any object into a `PayloadApplicationEvent` that you can use in your `ApplicationEventListener` and act on it. This works from Spring 4.2 and here is the official link: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2